# iOS Search Results Order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UISearchBar that searches a table of data. When a search is typed in, the results are displayed in an order like so:

Starts typing 'ch...'
1. Ache 
2. Cherries 
3. Choice

It makes more sense to me (and for my app) that 'Cherries' and 'Choice' would be at the top of the results, because 'ch' and not 'ach' was typed in. Is this something that can be changed programatically, or is it just the way iOS searches work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the search option as **NSAnchoredSearch**

**NSRange searchRange = [sortedString rangeOfString:searchText options:NSAnchoredSearch];**

Some of the search method listed below

**NSCaseInsensitiveSearch**

**NSLiteralSearch**

**NSBackwardsSearch**

**NSAnchoredSearch**

**NSNumericSearch**

**NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch**

**NSWidthInsensitiveSearch**

**NSForcedOrderingSearch**

**NSRegularExpressionSearch**

Eg:

```
- (void)search {

    NSString *searchText = [searchBar.text lowercaseString];


    for (int index = 0; index < [availableCollectionArray count]; index++) {

        NSArray *tempArray = [availableCollectionArray objectAtIndex:index];

        for (int tempIndex = 0; tempIndex < [tempArray count] ; tempIndex++) {

            NSString *sortedString = [tempArray objectAtIndex:tempIndex];

            NSRange searchRange = [sortedString rangeOfString:searchText options:NSAnchoredSearch];

            if (searchRange.length > 0)
            {
                [sortedArray addObject: sortedString];  //add the string which starts from searchBar.text
            }       

        }   

    }

}
```