# How to Search in UITableview Using UISearhBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsstring, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Search Results Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533204/ios-search-results-order)

When i Search some thing in **UITableview** Using **UISearchBar** nothing is appear in my UITableview after making Search in UISearch.Before Searching my Table show all the data That i have in my PList.I am Facing Search Problem When i have **Plist Data** in Such a Formate.as my Sreenshot show Below

[image]
My code is Given Below.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    pArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pArray forKey:@"Countries"];
[listOfItems addObject:dic];
sArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Songs" 
        ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
pArray = [[dic objectForKey:@"A"]retain];
[tableView reloadData];
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (searching){
      return [sArray count];
}
  else {  
       return [pArray count];
     }
  }


- (void) searchTableView
  {
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
{
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
}

for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        [sArray addObject:sTemp];
}

[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil;

}
```

When i use Breakpoint in **searchTableView** Method String **SearchText** show the Text which it Currenty have But my NSArray **Array** Show Zero objects and My NSString **sTemp** show **Variable is not CFString**.Can Some on help to Fix it.Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Do you ever tell it to reload data? Put a breakpoint in numberifrowsinsection to check if that ever gets called. Also are you using the delegate methods for a searchresultscontroller?

Comment: see my answer, this may help you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533204/ios-search-results-order/11534230#11534230